# How to get muiltibody plant from MakeManipulationStation()

Tags: drake

My code:
https://deepnote.com/project/IIWA-ARM-WITH-COLLISONS-VmNCT6XuS7yKITvWjqLY1g/%2Fnotebook.ipynb
(should be set to anyone with link can view)

Using Russ's "Set up a basic ManipulationStation diagram," I tried using a manipulation station to make an iiwa arm controller for the dense sphere collision iiwa urdf.

When I try to use

```
builder = DiagramBuilder()
station = builder.AddSystem(MakeManipulationStation())
plant = station.get_multibody_plant()
```

the code gives me an error that the diagram does not have the attribute. I am trying to use the MakeManipulationStation() just like the regular ManipulationStation is used in Russ's course notes. How should I go about getting the multibody plant from MakeManipulationStation()?

Answer (score 0):

That is because your `MakeManipulationStation()` method returns an object of type `Diagram`. There is no API in `Diagram` that is specific to multibody plant (and there should not be any).

The error message you get is consistent:

> AttributeError: 'Diagram_[float]' object has no attribute 'get_multibody_plant'

That is telling that there is no method called `get_multibody_plant()` in an object of type `Diagram` (or `Diagram_[float]` to be more specific).

You could use something like `plant = station.GetSubsystemByName("plant")`